# Creating 3 panels on a CSS Page Text won't align

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /* Adjust the font as needed */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide overflow content beyond the viewport */
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 2px auto;
  /* Three columns: left image, divider, right text */
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-container {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* Align the image to the top */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide overflow content beyond the viewport */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.text-container {
  grid-column: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* Align the text to the top */
  align-items: center;
  /* Center horizontally within the text container */
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  /* Set the height of the horizontal divider */
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 20px 0;
  /* Add some margin for spacing */
}

.top-text,
.bottom-text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* Set background color for text areas */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg/1200px-SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg.png" alt="Your Image">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="top-text">TOP TEXT HERE</div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="bottom-text">BOTTOM TEXT HERE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The issue I'm running into is I want the divider to always stay in the middle of the image, and the TOP TEXT box to always start by being aligned with the top of the image, extending to the divider.  So it creates 3 panels of sorts.

What am I misunderstanding?

My thought process is there is a container that holds all of this, then a container for the top text area, bottom text area, and image.  The image and divider are working as expected, I think, same with the bottom text, but the top text seems to always default to the lower position and I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your snippet, simplifed and used `display: flex` instead for the entire container and for right panel. By using `justify-content: flex-end/start` on the top/bottom text we can control where they start in the vertical direction.

By using `flex: 100% 0 1` we set top/bottom to try to occupy 100% each, shrinking if needed and disabling growing so they don't get taller than the image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 100% 0 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bottom {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.text {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg/1200px-SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg.png" alt="Your Image">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="top">
      <span class="text">TOP TEXT HERE</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="bottom">
      <span class="text">BOTTOM TEXT HERE</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```